# Failing to build a custom Asterisk PJSIP module

Tags: gcc, asterisk, sip, pjsip

I am trying to create a custom Asterisk PJSIP module that can:

- 1) analyse incoming sip messages
- 2) print info from sip header into log/console

Here is my code (simplified) :

```
 #include "asterisk.h"
ASTERISK_REGISTER_FILE()

#ifndef AST_MODULE
#define AST_MODULE "res_modul"
#endif

//bunch of libraries here

static pj_bool_t logging_on_rx_msg(pjsip_rx_data *rdata);

static pj_bool_t logging_on_rx_msg(pjsip_rx_data *rdata)
{
    char *method;
    method= rdata->pkt_info.packet;
    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE,"SIP METHOD is: %.8s \n",method);



        return PJ_SUCCESS;
}




static pjsip_module logging_module = {
    .name = { "Test module", 20 },
    .priority = 0,
    .on_rx_request = logging_on_rx_msg,
    .on_rx_response = logging_on_rx_msg,

};


static int load_module(void)
{
     CHECK_PJSIP_MODULE_LOADED();
    ast_log(AST_LOG_WARNING, "Success in loading!");
    ast_sip_register_service(&logging_module);
    return AST_MODULE_LOAD_SUCCESS;
}

static int unload_module(void)
{
    ast_sip_unregister_service(&logging_module);
    return 0;
}

AST_MODULE_INFO(ASTERISK_GPL_KEY, AST_MODFLAG_LOAD_ORDER, "Test module",
    .support_level = AST_MODULE_SUPPORT_EXTENDED,
    .load = load_module,
    .unload = unload_module,
    .load_pri = AST_MODPRI_DEFAULT,
);
```

When I try to compile Asterisk with my module i get a compilation error:

```
menuselect/menuselect --check-deps menuselect.makeopts
   [CC] res_modul.c -> res_modul.o
   [LD] res_modul.o -> res_modul.so
   [LD] res_pjsip.o res_pjsip/security_events.o res_pjsip/pjsip_options.o res_pjsip/location.o res_pjsip/config_global.o res_pjsip/pjsip_transport_events.o res_pjsip/presence_xml.o res_pjsip/pjsip_resolver.o res_pjsip/config_system.o res_pjsip/config_domain_aliases.o res_pjsip/config_transport.o res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.o res_pjsip/pjsip_configuration.o res_pjsip/res_modul.o res_pjsip/pjsip_session.o res_pjsip/pjsip_message_filter.o res_pjsip/pjsip_global_headers.o res_pjsip/pjsip_transport_management.o res_pjsip/pjsip_cli.o res_pjsip/config_auth.o res_pjsip/pjsip_scheduler.o -> res_pjsip.so
res_pjsip/res_modul.o: In function `__internal_res_pjsip_self':
/usr/local/src/asterisk-14.7.6/res/res_pjsip/res_modul.c:136: multiple definition of `__internal_res_pjsip_self'
res_pjsip.o:/usr/local/src/asterisk-14.7.6/res/res_pjsip.c:4918: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what causes this, there's no definition of `__internal_res_pjsip_self' in the source code. Not in my module, not in the res_pjsip.c file. According to the compilation error, its defined in res_pjsip.c:4918, but at that line is just the AST_MODULE_INFO.

Answer (score 0):

AST_MODULE_INFO is macros which return function  you refer into code.

Read more about C preprocessing and debuging